# Set the MaxConnectionsPerServer when using HttpClientFactory

Tags: c#, .net-core, dotnet-httpclient

When instantiating a `HttpClient`, I can specify...

```
var socketsHandler = new SocketsHttpHandler
{
    PooledConnectionLifetime = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10),
    PooledConnectionIdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5),
    MaxConnectionsPerServer = 10
};

var client = new HttpClient(socketsHandler);
```

The code I'm working with uses the `HttpClientFactory` to instantiate a new `HttpClient`.  Is there a way to do a similar thing, so I can restrict the `MaxConnectionsPerServer` whilst using `HttpClientFactory`?

Comment: Did you find out anything? I have same question!

Comment: I think I found you couldn't do the same thing using HttpClientFactory. I think one is a.NET Core feature and the other a .NET Standard feature.

Comment: It is also available in .NET Framework 4.7.1, 4.7.2 and 4.8 where it is default max 2 connections

Answer (score 5):

You can try following :

```
self.AddHttpClient<TInterface, TClass>()
    .ConfigureHttpClient((provider, client) =>
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("base api address");
        client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15);
    })
    // should return a new instance each time the function is called
   .ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(
       () => new SocketsHttpHandler
       {
          MaxConnectionsPerServer = 100,
          //PooledConnectionLifetime = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15),  //This is infinite by default
          PooledConnectionIdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15),
       });
```

Comment: ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler should return a new instance each time it is invoked